# Get x position value from cursor location in windows form to integer c#

Tags: c#, integer, int, var

I'm currently trying to get an option displayed if my mouse cursor is (this.Width - 200) from the right. Is it possible to get the integer value of the variable?

So far, I've ended up converting the value back and forth, it looks messy and it even gets a crash.

Here is the code:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var relativePoint = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position); //Output will look something like this: "{X=1016,Y=237}"

    string Xpos = relativePoint.ToString(); //convert to string
    int startIndex = Xpos.IndexOf("{X=") + "{X=".Length;
    int endIndex = Xpos.IndexOf(",Y=");
    string newString = Xpos.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex); //Only get X value

    int XposINT = Int32.Parse(Xpos); //Convert to int

    if (XposINT >= this.Width - 200)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("cursor is at the edge of the form.");
    }

}
```

Are there an easier way to do it? Is it possible to direct convert the variable to an integer?

Please help

Comment: Why not just take the X and Y of the point?

Comment: Why all this code? A point has X and Y properties already there for you

Comment: @Steve Basically because I didn't know. This is what stack overflow is for. Other people might come here and look at your comments, answers because they didn't know either.

Comment: One additional comment, using `Cursor.Position` is also unnecessary.  The `MouseEventArgs` that is passed into your event handler has the mouse coordinates already:  `e.X` and `e.Y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `relativePoint.X`

Comment: Wow that was so fast, thanks a lot. I'll confirm as the answer as soon as 7 min has past.